# What is the name of the circle that is tangent to three mutually-tangent circles centered at the vertices of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, soddy-circles

I want some information about the little 'tangent circle', but I don't have its name to search for it in the internet. What is it called?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that's the [Inner Soddy Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerSoddyCircle.html).

Answer (score 14):

I think that (inner) [Soddy circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoddyCircles.html) is what you want.